# Is there a way I can use a loop to make a 'forever' kind of statement?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make my interactive car game again, but this time I am doing my speed limits. I tried doing while the speed of the car is more than the speed limit plus 10, then execute the code. But it doesn't work at all. It's not even giving me an error in the console. Here is my code:

```js
var carOn = 0;
var lBlink = 0;
var rBlink = 0;
var time = 'day';
var change = setInterval(changeDay, 120000);
var blink = '';
var lblink = '';
var headlights = 0;
var mph = 0;
var accelerate = setInterval(accelerate, 500);
var gear = 'park';
var overSpeedLimit = false;
var speedLimit = 25;

console.log('Time to start the day!');

function toggleCar() {
 var min = 1;
 var max = 6;
 let starts = Math.random() * (+max - +min) + +min;
 if (carOn == 0) {
  if (condition == 'bad') {
   if (starts >= 5) {
    console.log('Car on');
    document.getElementById('carIgnition').innerHTML = 'Your car is on';
   } else {
    console.log('Your car must be broken...');
    document.getElementById('carIgnition').innerHTML = 'Your car did not start';
    setTimeout(function() {
     document.getElementById('carIgnition').innerHTML = 'Your car is off';
    }, 3000);
   }
  } else {
   console.log('Car on');
   document.getElementById('carIgnition').innerHTML = 'Your car is on';
  }
 } else {
  console.log('Car off');
  document.getElementById('carIgnition').innerHTML = 'Your car is off';
 }
}

var condition = '';

function setupCar() {
 var make = window.prompt('What is the make of your car?', 'Dodge');
 var model = window.prompt('What is the model of your car?', 'Charger');
 var year = window.prompt('What year is your car?', '2018');
 condition = window.prompt('What condition is your car in?');
 document.getElementById('typeCar').innerHTML = make + ' ' + model + ' ' + year;
 document.getElementById('condition').innerHTML = 'Condition: ' + condition;
 document.getElementById('hideMe').style.display = 'none';
 console.log('You bought a nice ' + make + ' ' + model + ' ' + year + ' in ' + condition + ' condition.');
}

function rightBlinker() {
 if (rBlink == 0) {
  rBlink = 1;
  document.getElementById('rBlinker').innerHTML = 'Your right blinker is on &rarr;';
  console.log('Right blinker on');
 } else if (rBlink == 1) {
  rBlink = 0;
  console.log('Right blinker off');
  document.getElementById('rBlinker').innerHTML = 'Your right blinker is off';
 }
}

function leftBlinker() {
 if (lBlink == 0) {
  lBlink = 1;
  document.getElementById('lBlinker').innerHTML = 'Your left blinker is on &larr;';
  console.log('Left blinker on');
 } else if (lBlink == 1) {
  lBlink = 0;
  document.getElementById('lBlinker').innerHTML = 'Your left blinker is off';
  console.log('Left blinker off');
 }
}

function toggleHeadlights() {
 if (headlights == 0) {
  headlights = 1;
  document.getElementById('headlights').innerHTML = 'Your headlights are on';
  document.getElementById('headlights').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  console.log('Headlights on');
 } else if (headlights == 1) {
  headlights = 0;
  document.getElementById('headlights').innerHTML = 'Your headlights are off';
  document.getElementById('headlights').style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  console.log('Headlights off');
 }
}

function changeDay() {
 if (time == 'day') {
  time = 'night';
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = 'It is night time right now';
  console.log('It is night time, time to go home.');
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
 } else if (time == 'night') {
  time = 'day';
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = 'It is day time right now';
  console.log('It is now day time, go to work!');
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'powderblue';
 }
}

let wipers;

function toggleWipers() {
 console.log('Windshield wipers on');
 wipers = setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById('wiper1').innerHTML = '&uarr; &uarr;';
  document.getElementById('wiper2').style.visibility = 'collapse';
  setTimeout(function() {
   document.getElementById('wiper1').innerHTML = '&larr;';
   document.getElementById('wiper2').style.visibility = 'visible';
   document.getElementById('wiper2').innerHTML = '&larr;';
  }, 1000);
 }, 2000);
}

function wipersOff() {
 clearInterval(wipers);
 console.log('Windshield wipers off');
}

function shiftGears() {
 if (gear == 'park') {
  gear = 'neutral';
  console.log('Gear shifted to Neutral');
  document.getElementById('gear').innerHTML = 'Neutral';
 } else if (gear == 'neutral') {
  gear = '1';
  console.log('Gear shifted to 1');
  document.getElementById('gear').innerHTML = '1st gear';
 } else if (gear == '1') {
  gear = '2';
  console.log('Gear shifted to 2');
  document.getElementById('gear').innerHTML = '2nd gear';
 } else if (gear == '2') {
  gear = '3';
  console.log('Gear shifted to 3');
  document.getElementById('gear').innerHTML = '3rd gear';
 } else if (gear == '3') {
  gear = '4';
  console.log('Gear shifted to 4');
  document.getElementById('gear').innerHTML = '4th gear';
 } else if (gear == '4') {
  gear = 'reverse';
  console.log('Gear shifted to Reverse');
  document.getElementById('gear').innerHTML = 'Reverse';
 } else if (gear == 'reverse') {
  gear = 'park';
  console.log('Gear shifted to park');
  document.getElementById('gear').innerHTML = 'Park';
 }
}

function shiftBackwards() {
 if (gear == 'park') {
  gear = '4';
  console.log('Gear shifted to 4');
  document.getElementById('gear').innerHTML = '4th gear';
 } else if (gear == '4') {
  gear = '3';
  console.log('Gear shifted to 3');
  document.getElementById('gear').innerHTML = '3rd gear';
 } else if (gear == '3') {
  gear = '2';
  console.log('Gear shifted to 2');
  document.getElementById('gear').innerHTML = '2nd gear';
 } else if (gear == '2') {
  gear = '1';
  console.log('Gear shifted to 1');
  document.getElementById('gear').innerHTML = '1st gear';
 } else if (gear == '1') {
  gear = 'neutral';
  console.log('Gear shifted to Neutral');
  document.getElementById('gear').innerHTML = 'Neutral';
 } else if (gear == 'neutral') {
  gear = 'park';
  console.log('Gear shifted to Park');
  document.getElementById('gear').innerHTML = 'Park';
 } else if (gear == 'park') {
  gear = 'reverse';
  console.log('Gear shifted to reverse');
  document.getElementById('gear').innerHTML = 'Reverse';
 }
}

var mph = 0;
var accelerate;

function gas() {
 if (gear == 'park' || gear == 'neutral') {
  mph = 0;
  console.log('This is the maximum speed for your current gear!');
 } else if (gear == '1') {
  accelerate = setInterval(function() {
   if (mph == 15) {
    console.log('This is the maximum speed for 1st gear!');
   } else {
    mph += 1;
    document.getElementById('mph').innerHTML = mph + ' mph';
   }
  }, 100);
 } else if (gear == '2') {
  accelerate = setInterval(function() {
   if (mph == 30) {
    console.log('This is the maximum speed for 2nd gear!');
   } else {
    mph += 1;
    document.getElementById('mph').innerHTML = mph + ' mph';
   }
  }, 100);
 } else if (gear == '3') {
  accelerate = setInterval(function() {
   if (mph == 40) {
    console.log('This is the maximum speed for 3rd gear!');
   } else {
    mph += 1;
    document.getElementById('mph').innerHTML = mph + ' mph';
   }
  }, 100);
 } else if (gear == '4') {
  accelerate = setInterval(function() {
   if (mph == 55) {
    console.log('This is the maximum speed for 4th gear!');
   } else {
    mph += 1;
    document.getElementById('mph').innerHTML = mph + ' mph';
   }
  }, 100);
 }
}

var brakes;

function brake() {
 brakes = setInterval(function() {
  if (mph == 0) {
   console.log('You are at 0 mph already!');
  } else {
   mph -= 1;
   document.getElementById('mph').innerHTML = mph + ' mph';
  }
 }, 100);
}

function stopGas() {
 clearInterval(accelerate);
}

function stopBrake() {
 clearInterval(brakes);
}

var stopLight = 'none';
var stopSign = 'none';
var stop;

function spawnStopLight() {
 if (stopLight == 'green' || stopLight == 'red') {
  console.log('There is already a stop light!');
 } else {
  var min = 1;
  var max = 11;
  var random = Math.random() * (+max - +min) + +min;
  random = random.toFixed();
  if (random >= 5) {
   stopLight = 'green';
   document.getElementById('stop').innerHTML = 'Green';
   stopLight = 'none';
  } else {
   stopLight = 'red';
   document.getElementById('stop').innerHTML = 'Red';
   stop = setTimeout(function() {
    if (mph > 0) {
     mph = 0;
     document.getElementById('stop').innerHTML = 'Drive';
     document.getElementById('mph').innerHTML = mph + ' mph';
     window.alert('You got pulled over for running a stop sign!');
     console.log('Officer: Oh my gosh! Why did you run that stop light?');
     var run = window.prompt('Why did you run it?');
     console.log('You: ' + run);
     console.log('It does not matter. You should never run a stop light. You could have crashed and killed you or someone else.');
     console.log('You: Ok.');
     stopLight = 'none';
    } else {
     document.getElementById('stop').innerHTML = 'Drive';
     stopLight = 'none';
     console.log('You can drive now, the stop light turned green.');
    }
   }, 5000)
  }
 }
}

function spawnStopSign() {
 if (stopSign == 'yes') {
  console.log('There is already a stop sign!')
 } else {
  console.log('Stop sign spawned.');
  stopSign = 'yes';
  document.getElementById('stop').innerHTML = 'Stop';
  setTimeout(function() {
   if (mph > 0) {
    window.alert('You got pulled over for running a stop sign!');
    console.log('Officer: What were you in such a rush for? You do not have to stop for long. Its not a red light...');
    var rush = window.prompt('Why were you in a rush?');
    console.log('You: ' + rush);
    console.log('Officer: Ok. I will let you off this time since it was just a stop sign. But next time you have to be more careful.');
   } else {
    console.log('You can drive now, you went through the stop sign.');
   }
  }, 5000);
  stopSign = 'none';
 }
}

function newRoad() {
 var min = 15;
 var max = 66;
 speedLimit = Math.random() * (+max - +min) + +min;
 speedLimit.toFixed();
 var roads = ['Oakcliff Road', 'Bartholomew Road', 'Main Street', 'Rocky Road', 'Matched Drive', 'Bandana Street', 'Cup Drive', 'Luis Street', 'Ridge Road', 'Carlton Street', 'Newfield Street', 'Washington Street', 'Wadsworth Street', 'South Street', 'North Street', 'East Street', 'West Street', 'Main Street Extention', 'Bradley Street', 'Dixwell Avenue', 'Henry Street', 'Saybrook Road', 'Google Street', 'Hawley Lane', 'Broad Street', 'Pardy Place', 'Green Street', 'Young Street', 'Old Street', 'New Street', 'Front Street', 'Back Street', 'Luther Street', 'Jackson Lane', 'Timbro Lane', 'West Main Street', 'South Main Street', 'Dontfraid Boulevard', 'Atkinson Place', 'Unity Place'];
 var roadNum = 0;
 var roadNum2 = 41;
 var road = Math.random() * (+roadNum2 - +roadNum) + +roadNum;
 document.getElementById('road').innerHTML = roads[road.toFixed()];
 document.getElementById('speedLimit').innerHTML = speedLimit.toFixed();
}
```

```css
h1, h2, h4 {
 color: red;
 font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
.middle {
 text-align: center;
}
p {
 color: blue;
 font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
button {
 color: orange;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
body {
 background: powderblue;
}
.weather {
 color: yellow;
}
.blinker {
 color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
  <script src='code.js'></script>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' />
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Interactive Car Game</h1>
  <h2>Car Info</h2>
  <h4 id='time'>It is day time right now</h4>
  <button onclick='setupCar()' id='hideMe'>Setup Your Car</button>
  <p id='typeCar'></p>
  <p id='condition'></p>
  <button onclick='toggleCar()'>Toggle Ignition</button>
  <p id='carIgnition'>Your car is off</p>
  <button onclick='leftBlinker()' class='blinker'>Left Blinker</button>
  <p id='lBlinker'>Your left blinker is off</p>
  <button onclick='rightBlinker()' class='blinker'>Right Blinker</button>
  <p id='rBlinker'>Your right blinker is off</p>
  <button onclick='toggleHeadlights()'>Toggle Headlights</button>
  <p id='headlights'>Your headlights are off</p>
  <button onclick='toggleWipers()'>Windshield Wipers</button>
  <p id='wiper1'>&larr;</p>
  <p id='wiper2'>&larr;</p>
  <button onclick='wipersOff()'>Windshield Wipers Off</button>
  <br />
  <button onclick='shiftGears()'>Shift Gear</button>
  <p id='gear'>Park</p>
  <button onclick='shiftBackwards()'>Shift Backwards</button>
  <p id='mph'>0 mph</p>
  <button onmousedown='gas()' onmouseup='stopGas()'>Gas</button>
  <br />
  <button onmousedown='brake()' onmouseup='stopBrake()'>Brakes</button>
  <p id='speedLimit'>Speed Limit: 25</p>
  <button onclick='newRoad()'>Turn Onto New Road</button>
  <p id='road'>Oakcliff Road</p>
  <p id='stop'>Drive</p>
  <button onclick='spawnStopLight()'>Spawn a Stop Light</button>
  <br />
  <button onclick='spawnStopSign()'>Spawn a Stop Sign</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

That is my full code for the game, so that you could run it and see what I made.

Comment: please add something more, like th outer part of it, where `mph` is changing.

Comment: i'm guessing that whoever voted you down did so because they don't believe you did much research on the problem. i'm assuming that you're really new to programming and stackoverflow. that said, it's not clear what the issue is because there isn't enough context about the code to know so my answer is just a guess.

Comment: I am not new to programming, but I am new to StackOverflow. I did do a lot of research, I looked it up on the web, then I looked at other questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

if mph is less than or equal to speedlimit + 10 the first time overSpeedLimit will never be set to true.

it depends on when that code snippet is executed. logically you might just want to set `overSpeedLimit = mph > speedLimit + 10;` but it still depends on where you test that.

Answer (score 0):

Using a while true/false loop will do the job. You can do:

```js
while (mph > 0) {
    if (mph > speedLimit + 10) {
        overSpeedLimit = true;
    }
}
```

That should fix your problem with not looping through.

Comment: Thank you @MaxPan, but where do I put the `while` code, do I put it in the global scope or the function scope? And if the global scope, do I put it in one of the first lines or is it possible to put it at the end?

Comment: @BraylanBB121 This will replace your original while loop for overspeeding.

Comment: It did not work. I tried doing that, and it still didn't work. It doesn't give an error, it doesn't do anything. I put the `mph` variable up to 10 mph more than the `speedLimit` variable and it didn't do anything.

Comment: This will lock up execution and loop forever if `mph` is between 0 and `speedLimit + 10`.

Comment: Hmm. @BraylanBB121 Can you send me your full code to see if I can help you fix it?

Comment: Also, it is not necessary to add the "while(overspeed)" You can have that in the other while loop.

Comment: @MaxPan I will edit the question to add the full code.